# Pack three largest sphere in a cube with given length.

Tags: geometry, spheres, packing-problem

I'd like to ask about sphere packing problem.
*The question is:* Pack three largest and identical sphere in a cube with a given length 1. Find the diameter of the sphere.
And can you kindly also draw the picture for me? I can't imagine that properly. Really thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this paper](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/download/v11i1r33/pdf), the optimal packing looks like this:

[image]

The spheres are of radius

$$r=\frac1{\sqrt2+2}\approx 0.2928932188134...\;.$$

And there is even space for a fourth sphere of the same size.